# UpdateCursor gives Too few parameters Expected 1?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, personal-geodatabase

Can anyone tell me why my script isn't working?

I can't figure out where I went wrong. I am working with an Access personal geodatabase. Adding a field, then updating that field with yes if the field Surface_Cover equals CONCRETE, or else it returns NO.

I am getting an error message "Too few parameters. Expected 1".

```
#import tools and set workspace
import os
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\sutton\Documents\Python\PythonExcercise/PlanoData.mdb"

try:

    #create new field to hold new values
    arcpy.AddField_management("SmokeMain","Indicator","TEXT","10")
    print("Indicator field added to SmokeMain")
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("SmokeMain",("Surface_Cover","Indicator")) as cursor:
        cntr = 1
        for row in cursor:
                #update the indicator field
                if row[0] == "CONCRETE":
                        row[1] = "YES"
                else:
                        row[1] = "NO"
                cursor.updateRow(row)
                print ("Record number " +str(cntr) + " updated")
                cntr = cntr + 1
#error checking
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)

#script status
ScriptStatus = "Script executed"
print ScriptStatus
```

Comment: I think you have a slash issue on your env workspace, change your slashes to / instead or use r'C;\....

Comment: I corrected the back slashes to forward slashes. The script executes just the same. It adds the "Indicator" field to the table and then gives me the error message "Too few parameters. Expected 1". Then it prints my variable at the end.

Comment: Tuple should be accepted, however have you tried a list as the second parameter instead in the cursor statement e.g. ["Surface_Cover","Indicator"].

Comment: with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("SmokeMain",["Surface_Cover","Indicator"]) as cursor:

Comment: Is this what you mean? I tried it and it gave me the same message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like `Indicator` may be a reserved word in `.mdb` Access Databases.  See **[Learn about Access reserved words and symbols](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Learn-about-Access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2#__toc262648755)**.

[image]

Changing the `Indicator` field name to something else eg `Indicator1` should work:

```
#import tools and set workspace
import os
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\sutton\Documents\Python\PythonExcercise\PlanoData.mdb"

try:
    #create new field to hold new values
    arcpy.AddField_management("SmokeMain","Indicator1","TEXT","10")
    print("Indicator field added to SmokeMain")
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("SmokeMain",["Surface_Cover","Indicator1"]) as cursor:
        cntr = 1
        for row in cursor:
            #update the indicator field
            if row[0] == "CONCRETE":
                row[1] = "YES"
            else:
                row[1] = "NO"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            print ("Record number {} updated".format(cntr))
            cntr = cntr + 1
    #script status
    ScriptStatus = "Script executed"

#error checking
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
    ScriptStatus = "Script failed"

print ScriptStatus
```